# Chinese Characters not being updated in SQL field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an update statement with Chinese characters in the data like so...

```
UPDATE table SET col1 = N'点心' WHERE id = 123
```

I am declaring the content type as UTF-8. For some reason, the field get updated with this:

```
è‡ªç„¶åœ°è§£é
```

The field is a nvarchar in MSSQL. Any ideas?

**EDIT

I am using a jQuery ajax call to write the data:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/call.asp",
    data: { value: value },
    contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg){}
});
```

** EDIT

Page 1 is:

```
<script>
var value = "<%=value%>";                                                       
jQuery.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "ajax/call.asp",
     data: { value: value },
     contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success : function(responseData) {}
});
</script>
```

Page 2 is:

```
value = Request("value")

IF value <> "" THEN
    SQL = "UPDATE table SET col1 = N'"& value &"' WHERE ID = '123'"
    objconn.execute(SQL)
END IF
```

Comment: "declaring the content type as UTF-8" - um - what's this bit about? There's no concept/option in SQL Server in which UTF-8 is a possible setting - so there's something else involved here than *just* SQL Server - and this fragment isn't enough for us to guess what that other things is.

Comment: Sorry, declared Content type on the jQuery post of the page. Editing...

Comment: As @Damien_The_Unbeliever said, your problem must be somewhere else, since this seems to work just fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/917c8/3

Comment: Can we see the code that sits between that ajax call and the database as well please? Almost certainly something, somewhere, is forcing a conversion to `varchar` instead of `nvarchar`, but it's not obvious with what you've shown so far

Comment: Added the two pages, nothing else in between.

Comment: Instead of using `Execute` on the connection object, try creating a `Command` object instead, specifying the query using a parameter, and then add a `Parameter` to the command and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. My text editor wasn't saving the ajax file as UTF-8 UOM. Once it saved this way, it worked.